# ant "<input addproperty=..." not working from bash in linux

Tags: java, maven, ant, user-input

I have simple user input element in ant script (that's run from maven antrun plugin):

```
<input addproperty="myprop" validargs="y,n" defaultvalue="y">
```

and this works well on windows: the process stops until `y or n` entered in the command line.
But when this is run in linux prod box - after entering y/n happens nothing: the script (ant process) hangs until `ctrl+C`

I've found some [mail issue about concerning it](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/200710.mbox/%3C470B486D.3070709@apache.org%3E) and nothing else.

Is it an ant bug so far? does anybody can reproduce it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine on my linux desktop (RHEL 5) for the following dummy snippet using `maven-3.0.4` and `java 1.6.0_32` run from `bash` shell.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>dummy</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.dummy</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>Dummy</name>
    <url>http://www.dummy.com</url>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                      <target>
                          <input addproperty="myprop" validargs="y,n" defaultvalue="y"/>
                          <echo message="${myprop}"/>
                      </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks! Did you run it from bash?